# "/" in the Database column name

Tags: database

I have database with a column name "State/Province". All the queries and data transfers work properly. But in the "SelectedValue" property of the dropdownlist control, bind expressions throws an error.

When I edit the column name by removing the slash sign, it works well.

So using slash in the column name is not a proper way of naming?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically using anything different than:

- Alphabets
- Numbers (not at start of the column name)
- Underscore (_)

is not recommended as it is not a good way to name fields and some datasources might throw errors on other characters.

Comment: I'd even consider '-' a bad idea because it is also an operator. Actually these rules apply per default to anything you name in programs.

Comment: I agree 99% that the dash isn't a good idea i will edit my answer, thank you for your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Some good points about Column Naming convention:

- Avoid underscores, they look unnatural and slow the reader down.
- Never use a column name that requires [ ].  Shame on Microsoft for
  excessive use of ID which requires the use of a table qualifier.
- Use Proper Case, descriptive names and don't abbreviate.
- Name primary keys with a suffix that denotes it data type.

  - TableNameID for integer (the preferred choice for all primary keys).
  - TableNameCode for varchar.
  - TableNameKey (other data types).
- Do not change the spelling of the primary key from a parent table
  when it's used in a child table.
- Don't use acronyms unless they are well know by programmers or all
  employees of your company.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old threat, but if you're not the designer of the table and fields but just want to use the data, I would suggest you use:

```
SELECT * FROM <YOUR TABLE NAME>
```

You probably notice that SQL Management studio returns a field name for your column like `'State_Province'`.
This is the SQL fieldname that you can use in your queries